# Moving from ad hoc distribution to the store - will the current app be updated, or will the store version be installed as a duplicate?

Tags: ios, ad-hoc-distribution

I've been developing an iOS app that will soon be distributed via the B2b store. My client has been testing it for a few weeks with an ad hoc build. I'm ready to launch on the store with minor bug fixes, but the app will be largely unchanged.

The app uses core data and my client has been entering information that they would like to see retained in the store version. My question is, if a user downloads an app from the store, will it behave as if the existing ad hoc install is updated, preserving the clients information, or will it be installed as a fresh copy?

The store app will have the same bundle ID as the ad hoc version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the adhoc version uses the same bundle ID as the store version, everything should remain the same. If the client accesses the store page of your app, it will appear as installed already. Your store version should be of a higher build so his adhoc version is updated by the system.

Comment: Thanks. Will check this on roll out and mark correct if true!

Comment: What does 'higher build' mean?  The Build entry under Identiy on the Targets page in Xcode is a string.

Comment: @Bryan I meant a higher build number.

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't answer what I asked.  I raised this as a new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22612444/is-the-xcode-build-cfbundleversion-value-ever-treated-as-a-number

Comment: @Bryan See answer in your question.

Comment: @LeoNatan Will App Store automatically (offer to) update an ad hoc distributed app com.example.app version 1.2 once com.example.app version 1.3 hits the App Store? What if it’s a paid app? Is the behavior documented somewhere?

Comment: @user2962393 It should offer an upgrade, yes.

Comment: @LeoNatan If it's a paid app, will the update charge the user, too? Or will the app run without a receipt? Is this behavior documented somewhere?

Comment: If you send a user an ad hoc signed IPA, it should install. Later, when he tries to upgrade, it will ask him to purchase. Not sure about documentation.