# Is the XCode Build (CFBundleVersion) value ever treated as a number?

Tags: ios, xcode

In answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/22109738/448734, Leo speaks of needing a higher build number to force an update.  There are many descriptions such as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10091310/heres-how-to-auto-increment-the-build-number-in-xcode where people use this field as a number.

However, the field is actually a string, and empirically there seems to be no problem putting something like "3.8.3 beta 4c" in there.

So my question is: is this field ever treated as a number, and compared so that one is considered higher than another?  If so, how is this comparison done when the string contains non-numeric characters, or multiple decimal points?  Where is this documented?

Comment: Then don't put any non numeric characters and multiple decimal points.

Comment: I feel you have missed the essence of my question, which is: is there any _reason_ to behave as you suggest?

Answer (score 0):

The value of the string is not actually important. What is important is a new build appears in iTunesConnect, and so the AppStore. What I said as "higher build number" is what usually people do. You can go from "5.6.1" to "1.0.561" and it will be considered a new build.

Regarding a script, you can always create a post-build or pre-archive script that does some logic to increment a build. It's shell code, you can convert any part of a string to a number, increase it, and convert to string again.